# Can Elastic APM measure the performance of applications other than web applications?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

I've seen some APM that only measures web applications which run on WAS.

Can Elastic APM meausure the performance of other applications like pure Java application and etc?

If not,  can I use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/public-api.html (Public API) so that it can measure the performance of non web applications?

I will appreciate any advice. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key features of APM agents is normally in their framework integrations. The Java APM agent is mostly focussed on web frameworks — see the list of [supported technologies](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/supported-technologies-details.html).

But you already mentioned the [public API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/public-api.html) — if you manually instrument your code with that, you will still be able to use it. It just doesn't automatically understand the framework and you need to help it with that.

Alternatively, if your tool supports OpenTracing then you could use the [OpenTracing bridge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/opentracing-bridge.html) for that.